# How to maintain the Textbox value one time after submit button in Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, webforms

Actually i am sending the tweets automatically by twitterizer and get data from api JSON data from different urls. But when i put the url in text box and start the project it works fine and i am getting the data from text box but when the process goes to "Authorization of app" in the twitter and i press the "Authorize" button then page load again but at that time Request["textbox"] is null. Below is the front ed code. I am posting the data from one page like "Frontsheet.aspx" to TwitterStrap.aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" action="TwitterStrap.aspx" >
    <div style="position:absolute">
    <input type="text" id="text1" name="txtFirstName" placeholder="Enter Your First Name" />
        <br />
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

And this is the TwitterStrap.aspx.cs code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var text="";
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                 text = Request.Form["txtFirstName"];
            }

            using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {




                var jsonString = webClient.DownloadString(text);
                ProductsJsonModel Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductsJsonModel>(jsonString);
                List<Product> ProductsFromUrl = Data.products; // All of your products are here.

                // Your code
                Session["value"] = ProductsFromUrl;
                var title="";
                var cnt = ProductsFromUrl.Count;

                for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
                {
                    title = ProductsFromUrl[0].title;

                }


                var oauth_consumer_key = "myLtWOTLGtLsjNsm15tUUpdEX";
                var oauth_consumer_secret = "uC9yHjPPV83Olvq0I8zt9eMwyucIpUcO70NduqNx0JuPQVyDZB";

                if (Request["oauth_token"] == null)
                {
                    OAuthTokenResponse reqToken = OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(
                        oauth_consumer_key,
                        oauth_consumer_secret,
                        Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);

                    Response.Redirect(string.Format("http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token={0}",
                        reqToken.Token));

                }
                else
                {
                    string requestToken = Request["oauth_token"].ToString();
                    string pin = Request["oauth_verifier"].ToString();

                    var tokens = OAuthUtility.GetAccessToken(
                        oauth_consumer_key,
                        oauth_consumer_secret,
                        requestToken,
                        pin);

                    OAuthTokens accesstoken = new OAuthTokens()
                    {
                        AccessToken = tokens.Token,
                        AccessTokenSecret = tokens.TokenSecret,
                        ConsumerKey = oauth_consumer_key,
                        ConsumerSecret = oauth_consumer_secret
                    };

                    //TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> response = TwitterStatus.Update(
                    //    accesstoken,
                    //    "Testing!! It works (hopefully).");

                    Twitterizer.TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> response = TwitterStatus.Update(accesstoken, title, new StatusUpdateOptions() { UseSSL = true, APIBaseAddress = "http://api.twitter.com/1.1/" });

                    if (response.Result == RequestResult.Success)
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("https://twitter.com/");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("https://twitter.com/");
                    }
                }

            }




            }
```

Comment: If (!IsPostBack) will only fire if the form wasn't submitted. If the form didn't submit you won't have a request.form for the first SD t name.

Comment: Joel thanks then what should i do?

Comment: See the answer submitted by CodingYoshi

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I am not fully sure what you are trying but the downloaded products are in the session. Therefore, you can get it from the session once authentication token is provided:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var text = "";
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        text = Request.Form["txtFirstName"];
    }

    string jsonString;

    using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        jsonString = webClient.DownloadString(text);
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jsonString))
    {
        // Nothing to do so we return
        return;
    }


    ProductsJsonModel Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductsJsonModel>(jsonString);
    List<Product> ProductsFromUrl = Data.products; // All of your products are here.

    // Your code
    // All the products are in the value session variable so we can get it later
    Session["value"] = ProductsFromUrl;

    var oauth_consumer_key = "myLtWOTLGtLsjNsm15tUUpdEX";
    var oauth_consumer_secret = "uC9yHjPPV83Olvq0I8zt9eMwyucIpUcO70NduqNx0JuPQVyDZB";

    if (Request["oauth_token"] == null)
    {
        OAuthTokenResponse reqToken = OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(
            oauth_consumer_key,
            oauth_consumer_secret,
            Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);

        Response.Redirect(string.Format("http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token={0}",
            reqToken.Token));

    }
    else
    {
        string requestToken = Request["oauth_token"].ToString();
        string pin = Request["oauth_verifier"].ToString();

        var tokens = OAuthUtility.GetAccessToken(
            oauth_consumer_key,
            oauth_consumer_secret,
            requestToken,
            pin);

        OAuthTokens accesstoken = new OAuthTokens()
        {
            AccessToken = tokens.Token,
            AccessTokenSecret = tokens.TokenSecret,
            ConsumerKey = oauth_consumer_key,
            ConsumerSecret = oauth_consumer_secret
        };

        //TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> response = TwitterStatus.Update(
        //    accesstoken,
        //    "Testing!! It works (hopefully).");

        var prods = Session["value"];
        if (prods != null)
        {
            ProductsFromUrl = Session["value"] as List<Product>;

            var title = "";
            var cnt = ProductsFromUrl.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
            {
                title = ProductsFromUrl[0].title;

            }
            Twitterizer.TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> response =
                TwitterStatus.Update(accesstoken, title, new StatusUpdateOptions()
                { UseSSL = true, APIBaseAddress = "http://api.twitter.com/1.1/" });

            if (response.Result == RequestResult.Success)
            {
                Response.Redirect("https://twitter.com/");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("https://twitter.com/");
            }

            // clear the session
            Session.Remove("value");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yoshi .. But i am still getting null value when i click the " Authorize button" during running the process.

Comment: Yes i change it as you describe in your answer but after "authorization of app" var tweet is showing null value.

Comment: When did you put it into session? And at that point did it have value?

Comment: I put the session before the if condition and yes it has the value. and kindly check code now i placed

Comment: Please check the below answered portion

Comment: After twitter authentication, what is the value of `IsPostBack`?

Comment: IsPostBack value is false after authentication

Comment: I saw it but i just want to save the state of text box string not the producturl  can you specify it?

Answer (score -1):

CodingYoshi Please check it

```
using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
                {
                    var text = "";

                    text = Request.Form["txtFirstName"];
                    Session["Tweet"] = Request.Form["txtFirstName"];
                    var tweet = Session["Tweet"];

                    if (tweet != null)
                    {
                        // do whatever you need
                        text = tweet.ToString();
                        // clear the session
                        Session.Remove("Tweet");
                    }
                    if (!IsPostBack)
                    {
                        text = Request.Form["txtFirstName"];
                    }


                    var jsonString = webClient.DownloadString(text);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.